# Translation Manager Component Translation Percentage % Not matching with CME

Tags: translation-manager, sites-9.1

In Translation Portal, we are able to see, only 43% is translated (3 words translated out of 7):

[image]

If we click on Complete Step, it's reflecting in CME: 100% Completed, if we cancel the Task is showing 0%.

[image]

But actually, in Tool and CME it should show 43% only. Can you help me how to fix this?

Comment: Do these two Translation Jobs make up the single project entry in the {top} Translation view? Could it be that the cancellation isn't triggered in the translation view as it's in a workflow step that's blocking (I see it's in authenticate - perhaps the system is unable to interact until this/other steps are complete within the translation workflow)?

Comment: we are Re-translated Same Job after completion of First Job only. we have long time gap b/w jobs.

Comment: Your IT team or RWS Support would be able to investigate technical issues. Keep in mind the percentages seen in Sites are for the status of Components and don't reflect the individual translated percentages down to the word level. So in the example, it might be odd for the job in SItes to show 100% if it's not complete. However, it wouldn't show the more granular 43% translation progress.